# Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect form

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio, ado.net

Here is Oracle connection and command. I couldn't understand the problem:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("some sql connection connection");
    con.Open();
    OracleCommand md = new OracleCommand("insert into teachers",cm);
    md.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    return View();
}
```

Error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect form

Answer (score 0):

Check following points:

- The ODP.NET (i.e. `Oracle.DataAccess.dll`) is installed (Oracle Instant Client does not include ODP.NET)
- It has the same architecture (i.e. 32-bit or 64-bit) as your application
- Architecture of Oracle Client and ODP.NET must be the same
- Version of Oracle Client and ODP.NET is the same (even up to the minor version number)